# How to play MP4 (H.264 video) in Silverlight 3 (or 4) from a URL?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

So I have some URL of an [MP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4) file. I want to develop a simple Silverlight application to play it.

How to do it? (Preferably with example code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ole Jak,

Here is a suggested step-by-step:

Step 1: Create a sample Silverlight application with Visual Studio (File / New Project / Silverlight Application

Step 2: In your newly create project, edit the MainPage.xaml, and place the following code inside the UserControl's Grid

```
<MediaElement Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0" Width="400" Height="300"
     AutoPlay="true"
     Name="x_Media"
     Source="http://silverlightatlanta.net/Firestarter/Videos/TimHeuer_2.mp4" />
```

Step 3: Build and Run!

Jim

Comment: Strange, but it does not work in Google Chrome... And works in IE... (Bilt using blend)

Comment: I tried it, and also I thought it had failed to appear but discovered that it took a full 80 seconds before the video appeared.   So make sure you wait long enough for the video that I used in my example to appear.  Maybe Google Chrome downloads the video vs. streaming it.

Answer (score 1):

The mp4 file you trying to play does not contains moov header. That way, the player need the complete file to start playing.
I recomend that you run mp4box on the file to include moov headers.