# using mediaElement object to show clip

Tags: silverlight

I want to use MediaElement to show some small clip. 
But some of the clips format that i have are mp4, AVI ...

I try to load them to the MediaElement and 'play' tham but i can see anything. 
Is it possible to see them somehow on the MediaElement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **AVI** support in Silverlight (it missed on [overview of Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/overview.aspx)).
One way is to convert them to WMV with [Microsoft Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/encoderpro_overview.aspx).
For **MP4** files there is question on SO : [How to play MP4 (H.264 video) in Silverlight 3 (or 4) from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966215/how-to-play-mp4-h-264-video-in-silverlight-3-or-4-from-a-url).

Hope this will help.